# OPCUA: How to call nested method

Tags: c#, opc-ua, siemens

I'm tryng to call "Select" method using OPCUA Foundation libraries.

[image]

and this is how I call it

```
 NodeId node = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/Filehandling");
 NodeId method = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/Filehandling/Select");
 object[] arguments = new object[2];

 arguments[0] = new NodeId($"ns=2;s={filePath}");
 arguments[1] = channel;

 var callResult = this.OpcUaBaseDriver.Session.Call(node, method, arguments);
```

The execution raise the exception

```
BadNodeIdUnknown
```

I'm able to call methods like "GiveUserAccess" or "GetUserAccessRights" that are not listed within "Filehandling" folder in this way

```
NodeId node = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods");
NodeId method = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/Methods/GiveUserAccess");
object[] arguments = new object[2];

arguments[0] = userName;
arguments[1] = accessRight;

var callResult = this.OpcUaBaseDriver.Session.Call(node, method, arguments);
```

It looks like the problem is the nesting level of Select method within Methods folder.
Ideas?

Comment: _"It looks like the problem is the nesting level of Select method within Methods folder."_ I'd rather suspect `arguments[0] = new NodeId($"ns=2;s={filePath}");` to be incorrect. But I have no idea how you could verify or falsify that suspicion. What is the vaue of `filePath`? Does it actually exist? Is argument[0] of that method actually supposed to be a NodeId?

Comment: filePath is the correct file path to select, it exists within the CNC.  In the documentation that argument is supposed to be a NodeId.  I copied from the NodeId propriety I found using UAExpert

Comment: I suspect the nesting problem because a wrong file path will give a BadInvalidArgumentException (based on the documentation..)

Comment: Valid point. Have you been trying out different combinations. For example "s=/Methods" as node and "s=/Methods/Filehandling/Select" as method? Maybe there's also an example in the docs?

Comment: Yes, I tryed almost every combination without any luck.  The documentation, as example, refer using their own app not using a c# application

Answer (score 0):

For this method, you should provide the Node ID of the program you want to select, not the Node ID of the Method's folder...

Try something like

```
NodeId node = new NodeId("ns=2;s=/FileSystem/Part Program/NC_PROG1.MPF");
```

Comment: Nope, I tryed but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure about the node Id ? Look for one Program Under FileSystem/Part Program/ and verify the NodeId is correct.

Comment: What you are suggesting is right when you want to delete a file or create a folder, but to call that method I had to use the Method's parent folder as NodeId and the Method's nodeid as MethodId,  If I use the solution you suggest I keep on get the exception BadNodeIdUnknown.

Comment: "The "Select" method is provided under "Methods > Filehandling" in the address space, which allows the selecting of a part program from the NC file system. You can call this method and select the file to be executed by providing the node identifier of the file in address space and the channel number."

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the NodeID of any program file (*.mpf) ?

Comment: BTW what is the value of {filePath} ?

Comment: How can I upload a screenshot in comments?  filePath value is "Sinumerik/FileSystem/Sub Program/CAMBIO_PALLET.MPF", and it exist within the NC